# Query Firebase on javascript

Tags: javascript, android

I'm creating a quiz app and I want to filter my database questions in order by level and cateogory but I don't know how to do it. I've already implemented the levelRef to get the level and display it on screen.
I also want to fetch the category and filter the questions (e.g: if user taps on sport I'll display only sport questions).

Here's my code
`private void updateQuestion(){
        countDownTimer.cancel();

```
    mQuestionRef = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/question");
    mQuestionRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String question = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mQuestion.setText(question);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mChoice1Ref = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/choice1");
    mChoice1Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mButtonChoice1.setText(choice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mChoice2Ref = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/choice2");
    mChoice2Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mButtonChoice2.setText(choice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mChoice3Ref = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/choice3");
    mChoice3Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mButtonChoice3.setText(choice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mChoice4Ref = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/choice4");
    mChoice4Ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            String choice = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mButtonChoice4.setText(choice);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mAnswerRef = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/answer");
    mAnswerRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            mAnswer = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });

    mLevelRef = new Firebase("https://quizer-f3732.firebaseio.com/Questions/" + mQuestionNumber + "/level");
    mLevelRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            level = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mLevel.setText("Livello " + level);

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });


    mProgressQuestion.incrementProgressBy(PROGRESS_INCREMENT);
    mQuestionNumber++;
    timeLeftInMillis = COUNTDOWN_IN_MILLIS;
    startCountDown();



}`
```